# Android spinner OnItemSelectedListener not working order

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
.
.
.

     mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
     {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
           {
             System.out.println("aaaa");
           }
           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
     }});

.
.
.

}


private void function() {
spinnerMonths.setSelection(3);
System.out.println("bbbb");
}
```

when i am running this code I am getting

```
bbbb
aaaa
```

why it is like this. Why the listener is not immediately called?

I want to run the code inside the listener first.

Comment: whats the function() u have there? where do you call it?

Comment: first of all: Use `android.util.Log` instead of `System.out`. Second: Don't trust the order of a log, it is not guaranteed to be in the right order.

Comment: I am calling function() on action-bar item click